# Alter Table operations blocks replication in MySQL

Tags: mysql-5.7, alter-table, master-slave-replication

We are using Amazon Web Service's MySQL 5.7.26 with 4 read-only replicas. After some Alter Table operations we have found that the replication stops working. The symtoms are great replica lag that is only solved after rebooting the databases.

The problema has occurred serveral times. Sometimes even with very small tables (1000 records). This is problematic as it reduces our window to do changes that ordinarly would be done during working hours.

P.S: the engine is MySQL Community

Comment: Post the SHOW SLAVE STATUS from any problematic slave

Comment: Thanks for the ide @JesusUzcanga. I assume that we need to execute the command the next time we replicate the problem